# MySQL database not updating

Tags: php, mysql, database, sql-update

output from the database seems fine, but input from the update doesn't pass onto the database

edit.php - from here all values displays correctly

```
<?php
session_start();

$name = $_SESSION['name'];
$sur = $_SESSION['sur'];
$pass = $_SESSION['pass'];

echo $name.' '.$sur.' '.$pass;

//connect
$dbh = mysql_connect ("localhost", "xxx_admin", "xxx") 
       or die ('ERROR!');
       mysql_select_db ("xxx_database"); 

$query="SELECT * FROM client_info WHERE (first='$name' AND last='$sur' AND password='$pass')";
$result=mysql_query($query);


    $id = mysql_result($result,$i,"id");
    $first = mysql_result($result,$i,"first");
    $last = mysql_result($result,$i,"last");
    $phone = mysql_result($result,$i,"phone");
    $mob = mysql_result($result,$i,"mob");
    $fax = mysql_result($result,$i,"fax");
    $email = mysql_result($result,$i,"email");
    $web = mysql_result($result,$i,"web");
    $com = mysql_result($result,$i,"com");
    $add = mysql_result($result,$i,"add");
    $city = mysql_result($result,$i,"city");
    $state = mysql_result($result,$i,"state");
    $zip = mysql_result($result,$i,"zip");
    $zone = mysql_result($result,$i,"zone");
    $office = mysql_result($result,$i,"office");
    $office_num = mysql_result($result,$i,"office_num");
    $ext_mob = mysql_result($result,$i,"ext_mob");
    $ext_phone = mysql_result($result,$i,"ext_phone");
    $ext_office = mysql_result($result,$i,"ext_office");
    $srv = mysql_result($result,$i,"srv");
    $stype = mysql_result($result,$i,"stype");
    $voip = mysql_result($result,$i,"voip");
    $vpass = mysql_result($result,$i,"vpass");
    $regDate = mysql_result($result,$i,"regDate");
    $acct = mysql_result($result,$i,"acct");
    $Nagent = mysql_result($result,$i,"Nagent");
    $agents = mysql_result($result,$i,"agents");
    $password = mysql_result($result,$i,"password");

?>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>

<body>

<form method="post" action="update.php" name="gen">
<b>Personal Info:</b>
<p>First Name:<input type="text" name="first" size="20" value="<?php echo $first; ?>"/></p>
<p>Last Name:<input type="text" name="last" size="20" value="<?php echo $last; ?>"/></p>
<p>Mob:<input type="text" name="mob" size="20" value="<?php echo $mob; ?>"/>
ext:<input type="text" name="ext_mob" size="4" value="<?php echo $ext_mob; ?>"/></p>
<p>Phone:<input type="text" name="phone" size="20" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>"/>
ext:<input type="text" name="ext_phone" size="4" value="<?php echo $ext_phone; ?>"/></p>
<p>Fax:<input type="text" name="fax" size="20" value="<?php echo $fax; ?>"/></p>
<p>E-mail:<input type="text" name="email" size="35" value="<?php echo $email; ?>"/></p>
<p>Address:<input type="text" name="add" size="40" value="<?php echo $add; ?>"/></p>
<p>City:<input type="text" name="city" size="20" value="<?php echo $city; ?>"/></p>
<p>State:<input type="text" name="state" size="20" value="<?php echo $state; ?>"/></p>
<p>Zip Code:<input type="text" name="zip" size="5" value="<?php echo $zip; ?>"/></p>
<p>Zone:<input type="text" name="zone" size="5" value="<?php echo $zone; ?>"/></p>
<br>

<b>Office Info:</b>
<p>Company:<input type="text" name="com" size="40" value="<?php echo $com; ?>"/></p>
<p>Office Address:<input type="text" name="office" size="40" value="<?php echo $office; ?>"/></p>
<p>Office Num #:<input type="text" name="office_num" size="15" value="<?php echo $office_num; ?>"/>
ext:<input type="text" name="ext_office" size="4" value="<?php echo $ext_office; ?>"/></p>
<p>Website:<input type="text" name="web" size="30" value="<?php echo $web; ?>"/></p><br>

Old password:
<input type="password" size="20" name="oldpassword">
New password:
<input type="password" size="20" name="newpassword">
verify new password
<input type="password" size="20" name="verpassword">

<input type="text" size="20" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
<input type="submit" value="Update Database">
</form>




</body>
</html>
```

update.php - it says update success , but there are no changes on my database

```
<?php
session_start();

$ud_id=$_POST['id'];
$name = $_SESSION['name'];
$sur = $_SESSION['sur'];
$pass = $_SESSION['pass'];

$ud_first = $_POST['first'];
$ud_last = $_POST['last'];
$ud_phone = $_POST['phone'];
$ud_mob = $_POST['mob'];
$ud_fax = $_POST['fax'];
$ud_email = $_POST['email'];
$ud_web = $_POST['web'];
$ud_com = $_POST['com'];
$ud_add = $_POST['add'];
$ud_city = $_POST['city'];
$ud_state = $_POST['state'];
$ud_zip = $_POST['zip'];
$ud_zone = $_POST['zone'];
$ud_office = $_POST['office'];
$ud_office_num = $_POST['office_num'];
$ud_ext_mob = $_POST['ext_mob'];
$ud_ext_phone = $_POST['ext_phone'];
$ud_ext_office = $_POST['ext_office'];
$ud_password = $_POST['newpassword'];

//connect
$dbh = mysql_connect ("localhost", "xxx_admin", "xxx") 
       or die ('ERROR!');
       mysql_select_db ("xxx_database"); 


$query="UPDATE client_info SET first='$ud_first',last='$ud_last',phone='$ud_phone',mob='$ud_mob',fax='$ud_fax',email='$ud_email',web='$ud_web',com='$ud_com',add='$ud_add',city='$ud_city',state='$ud_state',zip='$ud_zip',zone='$ud_zone',office='$ud_office',office_num='$ud_office_num',ext_mob='$ud_ext_mob',ext_phone='$ud_ext_phone',ext_office='$ud_ext_office',password='$ud_password' WHERE id='$ud_id'";

mysql_query($query);

echo "Record Updated at ID: ".$ud_id;
mysql_close();     

?>
```

Comment: It says success because it has no other option as long as the DB connect works. Try printing out the post values and make sure you're actually getting values where you should be and for the record that is seriously insecure code.

Comment: Change: mysql_query($query); -to- mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: do one thing, echo your update query and paste it into mysql and see what error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I don't know your table structure, Try this and debug accordingly.

```
$query="UPDATE client_info SET first='$ud_first',
last='$ud_last',
phone='$ud_phone',
mob='$ud_mob',
fax='$ud_fax',
email='$ud_email',
web='$ud_web',
com='$ud_com',
add='$ud_add',
city='$ud_city',
state='$ud_state',
zip='$ud_zip',
zone='$ud_zone',
office='$ud_office',
office_num='$ud_office_num',
ext_mob='$ud_ext_mob',
ext_phone='$ud_ext_phone',
ext_office='$ud_ext_office',
password='$ud_password' WHERE id=$ud_id;";

mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 0):

1. of all i STRONGLY suggest you escape your user input before sending anything to the DB. it will escape special charaters and pevent use of keywords to mess your db. to do so, simply use mysql_real_escape_string() like so;

   $ud_first = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['first']);
2. You sould check mysqli as mysql being decretated. If your just starting your code, i usggest you switch as soon as possible. Efficiency and security will increase.
3. Add an ; at the end of you query. Will help the server to know where it ends.
4. change `or die ('ERROR!');` by or `die (mysql_error());` This will echo the last error encourtered by mysql server. It will most likely tell you what your probelm is.

I give you those hints as i don't see why your code don't work as expected.

Comment: thinking twice about it, it might be just an ' some where in you values that is not escaped that mess up the server.

Comment: host only offers mysql still don't have mysqli on my hostserver

Answer (score 0):

Something out of the range of this question but why assign each of the result values separately?

You expect one result and as $i not set is actually null it works
maybe you could simplify your life and code by using

```
$r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
foreach($r as $key=>$value){ $$key=$value; }
```

If there would be more rows expected or possible, you would have to close it in a foreach loop or similar solution. Other side, processing the post and securing input may be short&simple too

```
$allowed_post_vars=array('city','zip',...); // define ok variables
foreach($allowed_post_vars as $postvar)// each of them
{ $ud='ud_'.$postvar; // prepare longer name, like $ud_city etc 
  $$ud=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$postvar]); //assign it sanitized value
}
```